# AES encryption with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, cryptography, aes

im trying to encrypt and decrypt API requests and responses in my flutter app.
I've tried to come up with the following methods and somehow I don't get matching results from encryption to decryption. can someone help me to figure out what's missing here?

```
class AESService {
  static const String NCKXXL2 = '7061737323313288';
  static const String NCKXXL3 = "7061447324413244";

  /// Encryption
  String encryptIt(String text) {
    final key = enc.Key.fromUtf8(NCKXXL2);
    final iv = enc.IV.fromUtf8(NCKXXL2);

    final encrypter = enc.Encrypter(enc.AES(key, mode: enc.AESMode.cbc));
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(text, iv: iv);
    log('************* Encrypted value: ${encrypted.base64.toString()}');
    return encrypted.base64;
  }

  /// Decryption
  String decryptIt(String val) {
    final key = enc.Key.fromUtf8(NCKXXL3);
    final iv = enc.IV.fromUtf8(NCKXXL3);

    final encrypter =
        enc.Encrypter(enc.AES(key, mode: enc.AESMode.cbc, padding: null));
    enc.Encrypted enBase64 = enc.Encrypted.fromBase64(val);
    final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(enBase64, iv: iv);
    log('************* Decrypted value: $decrypted');
    return decrypted;
  }
}
```

The results are as follows

```
final loginData = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'};
    final str = loginData.toString();
    AESService().encryptIt(str); 
/// gives ==> ciiq+Nin44vlE5DojSzqi5agc/uuJsKvI/VhspHdckXHreptDhY0ECtUFdHgqmw5
    AESService().decryptIt(
        "ciiq+Nin44vlE5DojSzqi5agc/uuJsKvI/VhspHdckXHreptDhY0ECtUFdHgqmw5");
/// gives ==> �����D��~|�����47��o�Y#Z�|�(8nJ�Ks��[�\�
```

Comment: You should use the same key and IV for encrypt and decrypt !

Comment: .. but you should not use the same value for key and IV

Comment: You should also not disable padding during decryption, otherwise the trailing padding bytes will not be removed.

Comment: Note that a key is not a password. You should use a password based key derivation function (KBKDF), aka a password hash to derive a key. Or, preferably, you should use a key consisting of 16 randomized bytes.